# Objects and ArrayLists in Java

Tags: java, object, arraylist

For the assignment I'm working on I am suppose to make a crazy 8s game. What we are instructed to do is create a class that creates a new card and then a deck class that adds cards to a deck. Below is my code. My problem is when I try to print the cards in the deck, they all show up as 'KC' = King of Clubs. This is our first class assignment so I hope I'm just missing something fundamental.

My Card Class:

```
    public class Card {

        static int face;
        static int suit;
        static String[] faces = {"A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"};
        static String[] suits = {"H", "D", "S", "C"};

        public Card(int face, int suit) {
            this.face = face;
            this.suit = suit;
        }

        public static String cardString(){
            return faces[face - 1] + suits[suit - 1];
        }



    }
```

My Deck Class:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Deck {

    static List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>(); 

    public Deck() {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++){
            for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++){
                Card c = new Card(i, j);
                // System.out.println(c.cardString());
                deck.add(c);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deck d = new Deck();
        for(Card card : d.deck){
            System.out.println(card.cardString());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because both `face` and `suit` are `static`. All `static` fields of a Class are shared by all the instance of it. That is why for every `Card()` you create in the values are overridden and you end up with the last values as `KC` reflecting for all the instances. You need to make them instance variables, instead of static.

```
// In Card class
int face; // Instance variable
int suit; // Instance variable
```

That way, each instance of the `Card` will their own separate copy of `face` and `suit`.

As a side note, since the `deck` list in your `Deck` class is also `static`, it'll show the same behavior. Also, since its static, you need to access is using the ClassName and not the instance. Something like this

```
for(Card card : Deck.deck){ // access using class name instead of instance
```